# Do I have to see "Annabelle" to understand "The Conjuring 2"?

Tags: the-conjuring-2, annabelle, the-conjuring, the-conjuring-universe

Do I have to see *The Conjuring* as well as *Annabelle* to understand the plot of *The Conjuring 2*, or does the movie follow a completely new story?

Please avoid spoilers in the answers.

Comment: Not at all, better to avoid that film

Comment: They are both different movies

Answer (score 7):

*Annabelle* is a prequel/spin-off to *The Conjuring*.

*The Conjuring* and *The Conjuring 2* are the adventure stories of [Ed and Lorraine Warren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_and_Lorraine_Warren). There is not any special story link between these movies.

*The Conjuring 2* is a completely new story.

Therefore, you can watch *The Conjuring 2* without watching first part. However,

> If you are interested to know where that doll came from, you can watch *Annabelle*, but it does not have very much to do with *The Conjuring 2*.